# Problema con calculadora hecha con winapi y C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Estoy haciendo una calculadora básica con interfaz en C++ con ayuda de Winapi, ya hice la parte grafica (Les dejo una captura mas abajo) y ahora me falta terminar el código.

Ya pude añadir texto al Edit Control mediante los botones, quiero que al seleccionar los botones 1 y 2 se teclee el numero 12, el problema es que al hacerlo se sobrescribe uno número sobre otro, si tecleo el botón 1 y luego el 2 se escribe el número 1, luego se borra y se escribe el 2.

¿Saben cómo puedo solucionarlo? También me gustaría saber cómo puedo guardar en una variable los datos que están dentro del Edit Control para después hacer las operaciones.

Disculpen si son cosas algo básicas, voy iniciando con Winapi, les dejo lo que llevo del código, muchas gracias : )
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include<windows.h>
#include"resource.h"
HWND texto;

BOOL CALLBACK micallback(HWND ventana, UINT mensaje, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    
    switch (mensaje) {
    case WM_CLOSE: {
        DestroyWindow(ventana);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY: {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        texto = GetDlgItem(ventana, IDC_EDIT1);
        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
        {

            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"1");
            break;
            
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON2:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"2");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON3:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"3");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON4:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"4");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON5:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"5");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON6:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"6");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON7:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"7");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON8:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"8");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON9:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"9");
            break;
        }
        case IDC_BUTTON10:
        {
            SendMessage(texto, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"0");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE a, HINSTANCE b, LPSTR c, int d) {
    DialogBox(a, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), NULL, micallback);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento que describes es el normal, ya que el mensaje [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settext) establece el texto del control (tal y como su nombre indica: *establecer* `SET` *texto* `TEXT`).

Para solucionarlo, tienes dos opciones:

1. Antes de establecer el texto, lee el texto actual al que le anexas el nuevo número y estableces el texto del resultado de ese anexo.
2. Guarda en una variable el texto acumulado y usa dicha variable para establecer el texto del control.